# Do I have to iterate for image file path as key in nextkeyvalue() in custom RecordReader to read many image file?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to read images from hdfs . I have written my own custom implementation of imageinputformat & imageRecordReader.

In ImageRecordReader , in the nextkeyvalue method()--Here's [a RecordReader](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/RecordReader.html#nextKeyValue%28%29) API, do I have to specify the for loop for reading the images eg.  for(Path path:paths)  etc since I am specifying input form HDFS as image directory. Or it will read images by itself since images are split into various map task & each map will get image.

I am little bit confused here. Do I have to use for loop in methods initialize or nextkeyvalue() ? if yeas, where should i use it-in intialize() method ot nextkeyvalue()? (check above link method details).

Comment: Why don't you just write a `SequenceFile` with `<Text,BytesWritable>` instead of implementing your own formats?

Comment: @Thomas..thanx for reply.. i tried that but the output says input image is not a sequence file..so cannot proceed....

Comment: I have given you an answer how to actually do this in Hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just write a `SequenceFile` with `<Text,BytesWritable>` instead of implementing your own formats?

Example with some random images that you should store the paths in `yourImagePaths`:

```
// omitted try / catch and finally statements
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
Path output = new Path("/tmp/out.seq");

List<String> yourImagePaths = new LinkedList<>();
    // TODO fill your image paths here
SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf, output,
    Text.class, BytesWritable.class);

for (String file : yourImagePaths) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.copyBytes(fs.open(new Path(file)), out, conf);
    writer.append(new Text(file), new BytesWritable(out.toByteArray()));
}

writer.close();
```

Basically it writes the path as key (to identify back your image) and the raw bytes from the image as value.

Now you can read it in your Hadoop job and it will be automagically be splitted.
You just have to say that the input key is `Text`, value is `BytesWritable` and the  `SequenceFileInputFormat` has to be used.

Comment: This will generate the input of your mapreduce job.

Comment: Yeah but generating sequnece file for large no of images will take too much time..

Comment: Depending on how often you have to do it and how long you take to write your WholeInputFormat, it may be faster :p

Comment: ohh yeah..got it... i cant because again to take input from hdfs i need another sequence file..

Comment: @Thomas....is there any better faster way to read images? since there are somany ways to read text files but havent come across any for images..